# select items based on value first, then date order for all the others

Tags: mysql

I have a table with this structure:

```
| ID | TYPE | ... | ... | ... | TIME | ... |
```

I want to create a query which first lists all items with a `type` of `xxx` in date order, and then lists all other items in date order.

How do I create this query? I have never done this level of MySQL sorting using MySQL itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT whatever FROM whatever_table
ORDER BY type = 'xxx' DESC, `time`
```

The `type = 'xxx'` is a boolean expression and therefore returns true or false, 1 or 0. You can simply order by this. Since you want to have the one's where `type = 'xxx'` first, you have to sort descending.

Comment: thank you! If I could give a **Stack Overflow Cookie** I would do - please settle for an upvote and tick :)